# Can't assign id, "Column 'id' cannot be null"

Tags: sql, ruby

I inherited a database using Rails that doesn't set `id` incrementally, and also has two primary keys:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_user_history` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`history_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_login_id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`user_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`user_pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`app_version` varchar(31) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`history_no`,`id`))
```

However, when I try to insert into this table using ruby as such:

```
tuser = TUserHistory.find_by_id(user.id)
TUserHistory.transaction do
ntuser = TUserHistory.new
ntuser.id = tuser.id
ntuser.history_no = 0
ntuser.user_login_id = tuser.user_login_id
ntuser.user_name = tuser.user_name
ntuser.user_pass = tuser.user_pass
ntuser.app_version = params[:app]
ntuser.save
```

I get the error:

```
getName {"error_code":"Mysql2::Error: Column 'id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `t_user_history` 
(`app_version`, `created_at`, `deleted_at`, `history_no`, `id`, `updated_at`, `user_login_id`, `user_name`, `user_pass`)
VALUES ('v1.2.9', '2012-08-30 09:26:57', NULL, 0, NULL, '2012-08-30 09:26:57', 'userlogin', 'username', 'userpass')"}
```

Even if I set `ntuser.id = 9127` or some other value, it still says that `'id' cannot be null`.
I looked at other answers that say it is indeed possible to modify this value, but it seems as though whatever value I attempt to set for `ntuser.id` gets ignored.

Trashing the table and starting again in a sane manner is not allowed, as this table is already being used by our services.  I thought I'd create a new column for `user_id`, before I found out it didn't auto-increment, but even before getting to that step nothing, not even `ntuser.id = 0` or deleting the line that defines `ntuser.id`, works.

What is going on here?  Why isn't it recognizing the data is has been passed?  What is the best (no, fastest) way to fix this?

Edit: Rails version 3.1.0

TUserHistory class:

```
class TUserHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
set_table_name "t_user_history"
default_scope select("id, user_login_id,user_name,user_pass,app_version")
acts_as_paranoid
end
```

Comment: Please, share TUserHistory model and Rails version

Comment: Are you sure your `TUserHistory.find_by_id()` is working the way you expect? From the error message, it is clear that `tuser.id` returns null.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY (`history_no`,`id`)` is considered a single composite key.

Comment: @sumskyi - updated.  @Mark Thomas - `TUserHistory.find_by_id()` does work- when I ask the server to render `tuser`, it renders all the correct information.  With that being said, even when I use explicit int values (Like "12345"), it still says NULL.  @njk - interesting.  guess I have to read up on that then, don't quite understand how (or if possible) to send data to the keys that way.

Comment: Is the "save" method yours or something, from the framework (sorry, don't know rails)?  If you have access to that code that's where I'd be looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got around to doing it, by just doing an SQL statement. I wanted to use rails, seeing as how rails/ruby have wrappers for SQL code, but it just wasn't working.  In the end, it looks like:

```
tuser = TUserHistory.order("history_no DESC").find_by_id(user.id) #get last entry
    TUserHistory.transaction do
        id = tuser.id
        history_no = Integer(tuser.history_no)
        intHist_no = history_no + 1 #because this column doesn't auto-increment
        user_login_id = tuser.user_login_id
        user_name = tuser.user_name
        user_pass = tuser.user_pass
        app_version = params[:app]
        sql = "INSERT INTO t_user_history (id, history_no, user_login_id,user_name,user_pass,app_version) VALUES ('#{id}','#{intHist_no}','#{user_login_id}','#{user_name}','#{user_pass}','#{app_version}')"
         ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

The only other thing that changed is that the class description for `TUserHistory` had `history_no` added so that it would return with the `tuser` select call, and could then be modified.